# No one in the internet explains how to change the sys folder on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, debug, display-driver

I just installed Ubuntu in my notebook but it is not possible to change the brightness of the external monitor connected in VGA with the SO slider.

I did various research on the net and I came to a conclusion, the output device driver is installed correctly, in fact this is the contents of Intel's integrated graphics folder:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13 16:45 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13 16:45 bl_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13  2018 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 set 13 16:45 device -> ../../card0-eDP-1
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13  2018 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 set 13  2018 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 set 13  2018 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13  2018 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 set 13  2018 uevent
```

The problem is that the device systemlink points to a wrong port (internal connector eDP)

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1
```

while it should point to VGA-1

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1
```

I tried to change the systemlink but it is not possible to change the contents of the system folder /sys/ because I think it's a virtual filesystem.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have in `sys` are "files" that really point to kernel parameters used by various modules. So it's the loaded kernel modules which determine what you see under `sys`. It doesn't make sense to change it, because there wouldn't be a corresponding kernel module on the other end to process the changed files.

This is why "no one on the internet explains how to change the /sys folder": You can't change it.

Even if you could do that: Your eDP port has hardware associated with it that does have some kind of backlight. You can change the brightness of this *backlight* in this way.

A VGA connector doesn't have any special hardware for backlights (analog monitors didn't have backlights, and you just can't control the backlights of LCD monitors connected this way).

Now while you can't change the brightness of the **backlight**, you can change the brightness of the **image**, by telling your graphics card to map the colors differently. You can either do this with `xgamma` (though this really changes the gamma value, which influences the brightness), with `xrandr --brightness` and with `xcalib` to change the color profile or alter brightness/contrast directly.

If you want to change the brightness of the VGA monitor this way: Then I'd recommend using the controls on the monitor, the results will be much better. Changing the brightness via the color mapping of the image only works to some extent, using the controls on the monitor will give you the full range.

**Edit**

If you want to use DDC to change the monitor settings (which your monitor may or may not support), use `ddccontrol` or `ddcutil`. Note that this also doesn't "adjust brightness" in the sense the hardware backlight brightness can be changed by the kernel. Instead it's a generic way to communicate with the monitor, and tell the firmware on the monitor to do things. So this will be more or less equivalent to using the controls directly on the monitor.

Comment: Many VGA connections – even Carts – do technically support [DDC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) for brightness/backlight control, but as it varies between monitor models the kernel does not know how to bind it to sysfs "brightness".

Comment: Your answer is very exhaustive. So if I buy an HDMI cable and connect it to the monitor, can I then decrease the brightness from the SO slider?

My monitor is Acer G247HL (LED).

The problem is that the monitor is very bright even lowering the settings on it and xrandr ruins the colors of the output video.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "SO slider", but HDMI is similar in this respect to VGA - no backlight brightness, but the equivalent to a DDC channel (called CI). Though it's harder to access the CI channel, because not all HDMI encoders connect to it. I also can't say what controls your monitor supports, even knowing its name. If your default picture is to bright, the first things I'd do is to look at the [EDID information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor) your monitor sends, and see if it requires unusual gamma values.

Comment: Though buying an HDMI cable may be worth a try, because instead of sending the image information as analog voltage via VGA, and having the monitor convert it back to digital, you'll send the data digitally via HDMI, so the monitor may (or may not) display it differently.

Comment: I will try to interface to the DDC channel, I have only one question: can I decrease the brightness beyond the manufacturer's limit with an MCCS command sent to the monitor?

Comment: It totally depends on the manufacturer what you can do with MCCS commands, but I'd would expect them to be just another interface to the settings you can already adjust. Let me repeat: If your monitor image is off, and especially if the colors get screwed up with xrandr -brightness, I strongly suspect a monitor with unusual and differing gamma values for the three colors. So (1) check the EDID gamma values, (2) play with `xgamma`, (3) play with `xcalib` for a complete color profile.